# Changing music files auto next giving error and crashes the application?

Tags: objective-c

I have set the songs array to play one by one.And I call a method
 described below.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlayerPlaybackStateChanged:) 
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification
                                               object:player];

-(void) moviePlayerPlaybackStateChanged:(NSNotification*) sender
{
    NSLog(@"in state changed = %d and isPause = %d", player.playbackState, isPause);
    if (player.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStatePlaying) {
        [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
    }

    if (player.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStateInterrupted) {
        isPause =YES;
    }
}
```

playing 5 or 6 songs the app get crashed and last log values are as follows:

```
2012-04-18 15:54:45.026 SymphonyProject[2896:207] in state changed = 1 and isPause = 0
2012-04-18 15:54:45.027 SymphonyProject[2896:207] in state changed = 2 and isPause = 0
[Switching to process 2896 thread 0x603b]
[Switching to process 2896 thread 0x603b]
sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all

and go to the file objc_mesgSend and pointing the line:
0x0164a09b  <+0015>  mov    0x8(%edx),%edi
```

I m not getting the error whatever it is? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

One question, you access `player` object in `moviePlayerPlaybackStateChanged` direct - is it class property? Because you send the object with this notification, so you should get the **`player`** object by retrieving it from `sender.userInfo` dictionary.